# Install of Google-api-client Ruby fails on OSX Mountain Lion (localmemcache)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, memcached, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

Trying to install Google-api-client for Ruby on Mountain Lion fails due to localmemcache gem (I think).. Here is what happens:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing localmemcache:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        sh ./configure --prefix=/Users/rental/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/localmemcache-0.4.4/src/ruby-binding
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for apple OS X... 
->  Apple OS X is not supported because it doesn't have 
    sem_getvalue and sem_timedwait!
    You may set the environment variable LMC_FORCE_BUILD 
    to build a version of localmemcache that cannot recover 
    from crashes.
```

Important note: this happens, when installed with --development:

```
sudo gem install google-api-client --development --force --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where lmc is coming from, but its not a direct dependency of the library nor is it required for normal use. For now, suggest skipping the development dependencies and just install with:

```
gem install google-api-client
```